# SQLite Android Delete database row

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to delete a row in the sqlite data base. Please refer to the sql datastructure and my current delete method which is not working.

```
    private static final String[] TABLE_MESSAGE_FIELDS = {
        FIELD_USERNAME,     "CHAR(32) NOT NULL",
        FIELD_READED,       "INTEGER(1) NOT NULL",
        FIELD_SEND,         "INTEGER(1) NOT NULL",
        FIELD_TIMESTAMP,    "INTEGER(64) NOT NULL",
        FIELD_CONTENT,      "TEXT NOT NULL",
    };

    //more tables
    private static final String[] TABLE_MESSAGE_INDEXS = {
        FIELD_USERNAME, FIELD_READED,
    };
```

This is the structure, basically it is an instant messenger (IM) android app, so the user can send and receive message. While the operations like receiving message etc are working, the option to delete is not.

I am looking to delete the whole conversation between a user, in other words not the individual message in a conversation, but the whole conversation itself. I guess the right way is to find out the user name, and delete the entire row. The table TABLE_MESSAGE_FIELDS is contains the 5 columns indicating the message, I want to delete that entire conversation.

This is how I go about it

```
public boolean deleteMessage(String userName)
{

    SQLiteDatabase database = mLocalDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
    final String[] COLUMNS = { FIELD_TIMESTAMP, FIELD_CONTENT };
    final String SELECTION = FIELD_USERNAME + "=?" ;
    //database.beginTransaction();//do i need this?
    boolean result= database.delete(TABLE_MESSAGE,SELECTION,new String[]{userName})>=0;
    //database.endTransaction();//??
    database.close();
    return result;
    }
```

Comment: so where is the question then?...your code looks OK form me ... remeber ... it will not change data in ListView without more coding...

Comment: as mentioned, I want to delete the row corresponding to the user name, However, it is not working as intended. I mean the message doesn't get deleted from the database.

Comment: What is the result returning? And is there any exception?

Comment: Well, Finally it did work, I realised that there are more tables in my database and due to some naming terminology problem, I misunderstood them. The above method worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have correctly declared create query and everything works, your code looks correct so reason why your row(s) are not deleted from database may be that you provided wrong username i.e. each row in database not equal with given **userName**. Try to print your variable before perform delete action.

Then, you mentioned transaction. If you used it, you need to call

```
setTransactionSuccessful()
```

or your changes will be rolled back and database will be back to state before transaction.

```
boolean result = false;
db.beginTransaction();
result = db.delete(TABLE_MESSAGE, SELECTION, new String[] {userName}) > 0;
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
```

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: FIELD_USERNAME (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM messages WHERE FIELD_USERNAME =?                                                                                                                                      Not sure why ??

Comment: @Mikelbstek your column does not exists. check your table schema.

Comment: Ok ,I was manage to solve the no such column problem, However, the problem still remains. I can't delete the message

Comment: @Mikelbstek now what kind of problem? any error? you db is filled up? has at least one column given username?

Comment: I print the right username, I mean the owner of the message is rightly printed. Further, I get no SQL error, However, the operation has no effect.                                                                                                                                 Yes, There is one column with the username and I verified that I am calling the right username , however, it doesn't perform the action as it should. Further, In my list adapter, I also use the notifydatasetchanged() and remove item, but the message/conversation from the database doesn't get deleted.

Comment: @Mikelbstek Try to call `delete()` method without selection parameter. This should delete all rows and let me know what will happen.

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean deleteMessage(String userName) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (userName != null && !userName.equals("")) {
        userName = userName.trim();

        SQLiteDatabase database = mLocalDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
        // final String[] COLUMNS = { FIELD_TIMESTAMP, FIELD_CONTENT };
        // final String SELECTION = FIELD_USERNAME + "=?" ;
        // database.beginTransaction();//do i need this?
        String whereCondition = FIELD_USERNAME + "=" + userName;
        result = database.delete(TABLE_MESSAGE, whereCondition, null);
        // database.endTransaction();//??
        database.close();

    }
    return result;

}
```

Comment: doesn't work, run time error saying that column not found. In your code you are trying to assign the column name as the user name which is not right

Comment: FIELD_USERNAME should be your column name and TABLE_MESSAGE is your table name

Comment: Where arguments is the right way to go, concatenating strings is problematic

Comment: The above mentioned solution opens the user up to SQL injection attacks if the passed argument can be manipulated by the user (which it seems like, judging by the `userName != null && !userName.equals("")` checks and the `userName = userName.trim();` call). You are encouraged to use the `= ?` notation where ever possible and allow the system to bind the variables safely using the `whereArgs` parameter of the `database.delete` method.